# Multilingual App Toolkit build completed with errors - TFS read only files

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, multilingual-app-toolkit

I have added Multilingual App Toolkit to a ASP.NET web form application, in this application is used TFS for version control.

My problem is that every time the application is build Multilingual App Toolkit need to update the files, but it does not check out files before compile and so generates an error:

"Update xliff build failed, one or more errors occurred, multilingual app toolkit build completed with errors"

If I check out the files he can build normally.

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove any generated files from source control.

It is bad practice to put either binaries or generated code under source control. Source control is for the configuration that is used to feed the generation. If you need to add custom changes to the code after it is generated you should use partial classes.

You should delete all of the generated files in the solution explorer and then checkin. Make sure that you remove the files from the projects and solution as well.

After that everything should build, and continue to build correctly.

Note: Always take a full backup of your files before you make changes.

Comment: I agree with you when you say that is a bad practice to put either binaries or generated code under source control, however in the case of Multilingual App Toolkit each file contains its specific content with the strings of each language, at the time of build the files are synchronized, so I cant let them out of version control.

Comment: That sounds like a faulty design . Maybe switch to local workspaces where there is no readOnly...

Comment: Or customize the build process and run a command to remove the read-only flag, e.g. ATTRIB -R /S